# How to completely password protect excel file content in php

Tags: php

I use '**PhpSpreadsheet**' library to create an excel file, save some data inside it and then send it by email, these are lines of code that I use to create the file and password protect it, then save it:

```
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'ON');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'SK');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A2', $id);
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B2', $sd);

    // Set document security
    $spreadsheet->getSecurity()->setLockWindows(true);
    $spreadsheet->getSecurity()->setLockStructure(true);
    $spreadsheet->getSecurity()->setWorkbookPassword('PhpSpreadsheet');

    // Set sheet security
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setPassword('PhpSpreadsheet');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSheet(true); 
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSort(true);
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setInsertRows(true);
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setFormatCells(true);

    $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
    $writer->save('temp_dir/ls.xlsx');
```

I get all the above codes from official documentation [here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/samples/Basic/11_Documentsecurity.php). What that do is only protects the sheet cells from being edited, deleted, or adding new values.

While I want to completely protect and hide the sheet, so that no one can see it's content without having the password?
I tried more than one way that provided in the documentation, but none of them did what I want. Could anyone help me do that?

Comment: Possibly you are losing values because you chose to not follow the demo exactly. I followed your link. In their code, at the end, they use `$helper->write()` to write the final file. Did you try it this way too?

Comment: You are right, but I don't know where the $helper came from? Could you tell me that. And I use the 'Writer' to save my file.

Comment: That looks like a bug to me. Probably [this one](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/1411), but the authors don't seem to be very interested in fixing it. Actually [a lot of related issues](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues?q=is%3Aissue+password+) have been opened.

Comment: @Jeto, yes it seems to be a bug, but they didn't provide a solution.

Comment: Well, other than looking at other libraries, you'd have to look into the code behind these statements and learn what's actually needed to protected a complete document, and then submit a PR to fix it. I'm personally not familiar enough with Excel to help without spending hours digging, but good luck ;)

Comment: @Hunar there appears to be a `Sample` class you can instantiate and test their `write()` method, and see if that resolves the issue. If it does then you can study it to figure out how it differs from your code to determine why it works. ............. Here's the class in question from your original Github link https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Helper/Sample.php